# WordPress: Custom Post type causing URL errors

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, taxonomy-terms

I have a custom post type called `products`, which is defined like this:

```
register_post_type(
    'products',
    tp_build_post_args(
        'products', 'Product', 'Products',
        array(
            'menu_icon'     => 'dashicons-cart',
            'menu_position' => 20,
            'has_archive'   => 'products',
            'public'      => true,
            'hierarchical' => true,
            'supports' => array('editor', 'title', 'revisions', 'page-attributes'),
            'rewrite' => array ( 'slug' => 'products', 'with_front' => false )
        )
    )
);
```

Under `Pages`, I have a page called "Products" which has the URL (`/products`).

Under the `Products` custom post type, I have all sub pages of "Products", i.e. `/products/test-page`.

But, when I go to `/products`, the page is broken, it's showing me a page with all the building blocks under the `Products` custom post type. Whereas, if I go to `/products-2` (just a clone of the products page), it works fine?

Answer (score 0):

It is because of your custom post type slug and page slug is the same i.e. **products**. So the highest priority is the custom post type slug. If you want **products** as your page so you have to change the slug of the custom post type. Also, change the **has_archive** slug. After changing don't forget to save permalinks again.